# Conditional Expectation ( (finite) geometric given binomial r.v.)

Tags: probability

Conducts a sequence of 13 independent Bernoulli experiments, each one has probability $0<p<1$ for success, let $Y$ denote the number of success in the sequence, let $X$ denote the number of failures before the first success. Find $\mathbb{E}(X|Y=1)$.

My attempt: Clearly $Y\sim\mathcal{B}in(13,p)$, and $X$ is "(finite) geometic r.v."

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(X|Y=1)&=\sum_{k=0}^{12}k\cdot \Pr[X=k|Y=1]=\sum_{k=0}^{12}k\cdot\frac{\Pr[X=k,Y=1]}{\Pr[Y=1]}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{12}k\cdot \frac{(1-p)^kp}{13p(1-p)^{12}}=\frac{1}{13(1-p)^{13}}\sum_{k=0}^{12}k(1-p)^{k-1}\\
&=\frac{1}{13(1-p)^{13}}\cdot \frac{12(1-p)^{13}+1-13(1-p)^{12}}{p^2}\tag{$1$}\label{eq:1}\\
&=\frac{1-(1-p)^{12}\left(13-12(1-p)\right)}{13p^2(1-p)^{13}}\\
&=\frac{1-(1-p)^{12}(1+12p)}{13p^2(1-p)^{13}}
\end{align*}

where \eqref{eq:1} follows due to the following identitiy:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\cdot x^{k-1}=\frac{nx^{n+1}+1-x^n(n+1)}{(x-1)^2}.$$

The solution should be $6$.
Any suggestions will be welcomed.

Comment: I edited the question, maybe now it is clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two mistakes:

1. $\mathbb{P}[Y=1]=13 p (1-p)^{12}$. You got the exponent wrong.
2. $\mathbb{P}[X=k,Y=1]$ is the event that the first $k$ throws are failures, you have exactly one success ant the last $13-k-1$ throws are failures too, thus $\mathbb{P}[X=k,Y=1]=(1-p)^{12}p$. And note that $\mathbb{P}[X=13,Y=1]=0$.

Thus

$$\mathbb{E}[X|Y=1]=\sum_{k=0}^{12} k\frac{(1-p)^{12}p}{13p(1-p)^{12}}=\frac 1{13}\sum_{k=1}^{12}k=\frac 1{13}\frac{12\cdot 13}2=6.$$

Comment: In short, when there is a single success, it can by any of the thirteen trials with equal probability.  Therefore the conditional distribution for $X$ given $Y=1$ is uniform $\{0..12\}$. ...